# TPM error when trying to boot from USB into Lubuntu?

Tags: boot, usb, lubuntu

I am trying to switch my ~2018 HP pavillion laptop (i7) over to Lubuntu from Linux Mint.

I have a thumb drive with the Lubuntu ISO on it (done with etcher). When I boot into the thumb drive I am able to get to the screen that asks for my preferred language. It then seems to attempt to boot, but then it goes to a black screen and repeats this error message twice:

```
A TPM error (-1) occurred attempting the self test
```

Does anyone know what this means? Any experience with this error? My google searches aren't really turning up anything specific to this `(-1)`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you want to remove the error, go into BIOS/UEFI and disable the (trusted execution technology) function.   It doesn't impact boot in my experience, so if you're having install problem, did you *check-disk-for-defects* to ensure your download & write-to-thumb-drive was perfect (https://manual.lubuntu.me/1/1.3/installation.html)

Comment: @guiverc Thanks for your reponse. I disabled the trusted technology function in BIOS and chekced for disk defects. I received a message that the disk was fine, but I still received the error from above. I actually also received another error this time as well: `PCIe Bus Error: serverity=corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Reciever ID)...`